# HLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range error in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying `HLOOKUP` with `Importrange` formula as I've to lookup data from other Google Sheets.

I'm entering the below formula.

```
=HLOOKUP(C1,IMPORTRANGE("1wWguGb6O0GyX7ACxzoFCN8N73zV0pUeoj51R_zFNPfE","Project wise Resources!$E$1:$AZ$20"),2,0)
```

I'm getting the error:

> HLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range.

I have entered the correct range but unable to understand what the issue is.

Comment: This is a poorly worded question without data. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can't do that on the spot
- first paste this formula into some cell and allow access

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1wWguGb6O0GyX7ACxzoFCN8N73zV0pUeoj51R_zFNPfE",
             "'Project wise Resources'!E1:AZ20")
```

[image]

- then use your formula:

```
=HLOOKUP(C1, IMPORTRANGE("1wWguGb6O0GyX7ACxzoFCN8N73zV0pUeoj51R_zFNPfE",
                         "'Project wise Resources'!E1:AZ20"), 2, 0)
```

[image]

- **and also make sure that sheet `Project wise Resources` has a column `AZ`**

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess it was just the allow access thing that was required. It worked now. 
I had earlier created allow access for test data but not my actual data in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing last HLOOKUP option to TRUE/FALSE instead of 0

HLOOKUP: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375?hl=en

> Horizontal lookup. Searches across the first row of a range for a key
>   and returns the value of a specified cell in the column found.

VLOOKUP: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472

> Vertical lookup. Searches down the first column of a range for a key
>   and returns the value of a specified cell in the row found.

IMPORTRANGE:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en

you may need VLOOKUP depending on way your lookup is organised - by rows or columns..

If you are lookup up second row or second column only, then there is no need to have a range that extends beyond 2 rows or 2 columns...