# ARRAYFORMULA() with LOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a formula which is a combination of `vlookup()`,`lookup()` and `indirect()` functions:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C3,INDIRECT(LOOKUP("x",AD3:AH3,$AD$1:$AH$1)&"!"&"$D$3:$AB$325",TRUE),24,FALSE),"")
```

I need to convert this formula in a way that it is an `arrayformula()`. I have done the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C3:C,INDIRECT(LOOKUP("x",{(AD3:AD),(AH3,AH}), $AD$1:$AH$1) &"!"&"$D$3:$AB$325",TRUE),24,FALSE),""))
```

But, I am always getting an error with lookup part, which mentiones that *"lookup evaluates out of range"*. Any suggestions, where could be an error?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54716399/hlookup-evaluates-to-an-out-of-bounds-range-error-in-google-sheets) help?

Comment: Please share a test sheet